# Get refrence to surface object assigned to window

Tags: android, window, drawing

Is it possible to get a reference to Surrface assigned to window of activity?
I know that you can do this by:

```
 getWindow().takeSurface(new SurfaceHolder.Callback2() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceRedrawNeeded(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {


        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        // Draw view styff
            Canvas c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawRGB(0, 255, 255);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        }
    });
```

But as stated in the documentation this basically disables the view hierarchy. Is there a way to get to this surface after view hierarchy has been drawn so I can draw some overlay over it?